# What is the domain of $\frac{1}{\log x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If you ask to me what  the domain of $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ is, I set
$$
\log(x)\neq0 \Rightarrow x\neq1 $$ infact $\frac{1}{0}\to\infty$ but moreover (before this exercize) I would have set $x>0$ too because $\log(0)\to-\infty$. But in this case $\frac{1}{\log(0)}=\frac{1}{-\infty}\to0$ and the function is define for $x=0$ too.

Is this a rule? **I have to put log arguments $\neq0$ ONLY if logs are at numerator? There are other rules like this?**

*[edit]*
I got confused, the correct example is: $ \frac{1}{\log(|x|)}$ and so I should have put $|x|>0 => x\neq0$ in this case does something change?

Comment: The domain of $\log x$ is $x>0$ and you have to remove $1$ because the denominator becomes $0$. So the domain is $\Bbb R^+\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri May as well make this an answer get the upvotes 

Comment: Sorry i corrected it to $x>0$

Comment: You can continuously extend the function to $x=0$ by defining it as $0$ there, but it will no longer be defined by the formula $1/\log x$ at the origin. The domain of $x\mapsto 1/\log x$ cannot contain the origin.

Comment: "n this case does something change?"  Yes, $x$ may be negative now.  We must have $|x|$ is positive and no $0$.  That is $x\ne 0$.  ANd we must ahve $\log |x| \ne 0$ so $|x| \ne 1$ so $x\ne \pm 1$.  So $x$ can be any value except $0, 1, -1$.

Answer (score 2):

For the reciprocal of the logarithm of $x$ to be defined, the logarithm of $x$ must be defined in the first place. That means that we need to require $x>0$: The logarithm s neither defined for $0$ nor for negative numbers.
In addition, taking the reciprocal must be defined, which is only defined if we do not attempt to take the reciprocal of $0$. As $\log x=0\iff x=1$, we arrive at a maximal real domain for the function $x\mapsto \frac1{\log x}$ of
$$ (0,1)\cup (1,\infty).$$

Comment: Sorry i corrected it to $x>0$

Answer (score 0):

$\log x$ only **tends to** $-\infty$ as $x$ **tends to** $0^+$ i.e. it takes large negative values to the right of $0$ but it is not actually defined at $0$. So $1/\log x$ attains very small negative values on the right of $0$ but is not actually defined at $0$.

What you are talking about is the limit of the function $1/\log x$ as $x$ tends to $0$ from the right side, and it is well known that limits of functions may exist at points where the function itself doesn't exist.

Comment: But if I calculate $1/log(0)$ it is $0$, isn’t it correct?

Comment: @Francesco There is no such thing as $\log 0$. You are calculating $\lim_{x\to0^+}1/\log x$ i.e. as $x$ comes very close to $0$ the function comes very close to $0$. A function cannot take the value $\pm\infty$ so $\log 0=-\infty$ is absurd. $\infty$ stands for "a very large value", not some exact number.

Comment: ok it's clear but then why if I calculate with the calculator $ f (0) $ where $ f (x) = 1 / \ log (x) $ the result is $ 0 $?

Comment: The thing is, you can't find $f(0)$ because that would require for you to find the exact value of $\log(0)$. You are actually saying $f(0^+)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=0$ which is not actually $f(0)$.

Comment: Sorry i edit the post, in this case the right and left limit is equal to $0$, in this case does something change?

Answer (score 0):

The [natural domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function#Natural_domain) of a function (sometimes shortened as domain) is the maximum set of values for which the function is defined.

I suggest not writing any expressions like $\frac{1}{0}$ or $\frac{1}{-\infty}$ unless you are absolutely clear about the context and know consciously what you are doing about these expressions.

Your question has nothing to do with any "limiting" process.

First of all the natural domain for the function $\log x$ is the set $(0,\infty)$, or you may write $x>0$. It is meaningless to write $\log(0)$ since the logarithm is not defined at $0$.

Then you need to guarantee that $\log x\ne 0$ since it is in the denominator.

On the other hand, $\log x=0$ if and only if $x=1$. So the natural domain of the function $\frac{1}{\log x}$ is
$$
(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}
$$
or you write it as
$$
(0,1)\cup (1,\infty)
$$

Comment: Hi, I'd just like to say that I've watched you answer an incredible amount of questions over only one week of being here, and I really admire how much you are helping other people on this site. Thank you so much for joining us!

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: thank you for your kind words :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't over think it.

$\log x$ can only have positive input and int can have any positive input.  So for $\log x$ to be defined $x$ must be positive and $x$ can be any positive.

For $\frac 1{M}$ the $M$ can be anything except $0$.  $M \in 0$.  so for $\frac 1{\log x}$ to be defined $\log x\ne 0$ but otherwise $\log x$ may be any value.

So $\log x \ne 0$ and $x \ne =1$.

So $x$ must be positive and can not be $1$ but $x$ can be any other positive value.

So the natural domain of $\frac 1{\log x}$ is all positive values except $1$.

We may write that as $(0,1)\cup (1, \infty)$ or $\mathbb R^+\setminus\{1\}$ or many other ways.